# how implying Google Analytics API and Display them in asp.net mvc core 3.1

Tags: google-analytics, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web site project asp.net mvc core 3.1,
I want Display Google Analytics data on my project site
What are the steps to do this?

Comment: Please add more information

Comment: i think this may be your best starting point https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting